# What's the best graph database to start with?

Tags: database

I'm planning on switching from RDBMS to Graph database, can anyone recommend what's the best tool for beginners?

Comment: Can you define "best"? What are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know what the "best" tool (Graph DB) for beginners is. They all have a certain complexity and learning curve - it's in the nature of graphs.

I have worked professionally with a few I would suggest you start with [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/). This is based on the extensive documentation and learning resources available for beginners. Besides, it ranks highest of all graph DBs on [DB-Engines](https://db-engines.com/en/ranking/graph+dbms), so your newly learned Neo4j skills will not be wasted. You can download a free version for learning/practicing.

As an alternative, you could also look at [ArangoDB](https://arangodb.com/). It is also well documented, and even includes a [free certificate](https://arangodb.com/learn/certification/).

Whereas Neo4j is a pure Graph DB, ArangoDB is multi-mode and besides Graph also includes Document, Full-Text Search, Key/Value, and ML database functionality. ArangoDB has a free community version, too.